# php instagram api login error

Tags: php, api, authentication, instagram

I want to use API to login instagram. But I get error:

```
{"status":"fail","message":"Your version of Instagram is out of date. Please upgrade your app to log in to Instagram."}
```

And my php code:

```
function open($url,$post="") {
$cookies = 'cookies.txt';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        if ($post != "") {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Instagram');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER, "");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
}

  function _render_form($data) {
        $t = "";
        foreach ($data as $k=>$v) { $t .= "&$k=$v";}
        return str_replace("###&","","###".$t);
  }

function login($username, $password) {
          $post = _render_form(array("username" => $username, "password" => $password, "device_id" => "MY_DEVICE_ID"));
          $isi = open("https://instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/login/", $post);
          echo $isi; die;
  }
$login = login('MY_USERNAME', 'MY_PASSWORD');
```

I changed the device id to my phone's device id. But problem is not resolved... Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is you're using an out-of-date form of the API. Check the _current_ API documentation and ensure your code conforms to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram no longer supports logging in with a username and password. Instead, you should [use oAuth](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/#) to perform requests requiring authentication.

Using a library like [this one](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API) will be a lot easier than implementing this manually.